# Windows 8.1 contact lists

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

How do I access my contact list from my windows store apps. 
For example name,email and etc. I really no idea how to do it. Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225002 ?

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Phone 8.1 , I could read contact list programmatically by the following code. Hope this works in Windows 8.1 also.

```
        var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
        var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();

        var lst = contacts.ToList();

        foreach (var contact in contacts)
        {
            var mob = contact.Phones;
            foreach (var phone in mob)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(phone.Kind + "-" + phone.Number);
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(contact.FirstName + " - " + contact.Addresses);
        }
```

I know its too late since you asked the question over a year ago. But i think this might help some others in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if it's possible to achieve this automatically - just by code. Accessing contacts from code is somewhat restricted in Windows 8 (at least it is in WP8, but I believe this might be the same in Windows 8/8.1).

Anyway, it is possible to show a contacts picker (never tried it but supposedly it's pretty alike the one you'd normally use to choose a contact), please see [Quickstart: Selecting user contacts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/jj152724.aspx). The ContactPicker will return you a Contact object (or a list of), which you then can access, but I believe you'll be restricted to reading the contacts data.

Comment: The sample above only demonstrate how the sample contact already predefined in the apps which does not solve my problem. I want to get contact from the people apps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot programmatically read the contacts, which is a Good Thing. If you could, an enormous amount of spyware apps would do so and send of the data to their servers.

You can however allow your users to interact with contact data from within your application, through the classes in the [Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225002). See the [Building Apps That Integrate with People and Events](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-007) video for a good introduction.